# Is randint function in Python different from % trick?

Tags: python, random, probability, modulo

I appreciate your help in advance.

I wrote a probability calculator with python. Prob I want to calculate is this: What's the prob of winning when you try 6 times of game that has winning chance of 1%. So this following code is what I wrote.

```
import random as rand

total = 0
count = 0

p = pSum = 0

k = 6
n = 10000
m = 100

def pick(attemptPerIteration):
    global total, count
    for _ in range(attemptPerIteration):
        temp = rand.randint(1, 100)
        if (temp == 1):
            count += 1
            total += 1
            return 0
    return 1

for t in range(m):
    for u in range(n):
        total += pick(k)
    p = count / total
    print(str(t + 1) + ": " + str(p * 100))
    pSum += p
    p = 0
print(pSum / m * 100)
```

In this code, I used randint function to simulate one in 100 chance. The prob I expected is about 5.8%  but this program outputs about 6.3%. But if I use randint(1, 1000) % 6 + 1 insted of just randint(1, 6), program tell the prob is 5.8, which I expected.

What's going on in this randint function exactly? Why the old % trick works but randint doesn't?

Mathematical formula to this problem is this:
[image]

Comment: Because `randint(a,b)` returns numbers from `a` inclusive to `b` exclusive.

Comment: @CaptainTrojan See [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) python's randint includes both ends. It is Numpy's randint that doesn't include `b`.

Comment: As an aside, I think `1-(1-0.01)^6` would be a more concise definition for the chance of winning.

Comment: First of all, thank you for all of your help. I was total idiot! I should not count total when temp == 1, because prob I want is not how many 1 occurs in total attempt, but occurrence of 1 in each game. So, I should remove that part. And I didn't even reset count var at the end of each attempt. Plus, I can use just n for total try; var total is actually not necessary at all! Conclusion: randint function is totally ok with this problem, this was a human error lol

Comment: note: you should expect to get results in the range [5.4%, 6.32%] 95% of the time.  you can calculate this using with `scipy.stats.binom.ppf([0.025, 0.975], n, 1-0.99**6) / n`.  try altering `n` to see how the confidence interval changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you made mistakes with incrementing `count` and `total`. I changed your code to compute correct result:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVBLbsJADN37FBarUFBJVKkLJA7ADqkHQCOY0FGYj4yz6OlTe4xIVnhhe@xnvzcuf/yb09c0hVgyMZJL1xzRPWoGwJndHQ/YwiWPiWsGRUL5GaO9BgnfkMR3rRhEywCuvscSLkPjmH0sfPJ0ZE@OQ07rPaBYnwnPGJKy3fwboJr2ZLcK@1QXEjfdVrnWL0zosTGciFjMqpHnkRJ2sHiITNXAs4a4kDbO5aUQO8XmYL8bZna7ljSMQ9Uadmctq5IKfzA1skNEilvtcSVBawU/6o9sab2yEr32tWDztbPD@IRP0z8)

```
import random as rand

total = 0
count = 0

p = pSum = 0

k = 6
n = 10000
m = 100

def pick(attemptPerIteration):
    for _ in range(attemptPerIteration):
        temp = rand.randint(1, 100)
        if (temp == 1):
            return 1
    return 0

for t in range(m):
    for u in range(n):
        count += pick(k)
        total += 1
    p = count / total
    print(str(t + 1) + ": " + str(p * 100))
    pSum += p
    p = 0
print(pSum / m * 100)
```

Output:

```
.......
90: 5.822555555555556
91: 5.8221978021978025
92: 5.822608695652174
93: 5.824193548387097
94: 5.822446808510638
95: 5.822631578947368
96: 5.824166666666667
97: 5.825670103092784
98: 5.8254081632653065
99: 5.826969696969697
100: 5.8306
5.825542887205491
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `m = 100` and `n = 10000` are too little for things to converge.

```
import random

def did_win(attempts):
    return any(random.random() < .01 for attempt in range(attempts))

tries = [did_win(6) for x in range(1_000_000)]
print(tries.count(True) / len(tries))
```

prints out about `0.058039` which seems close enough.

If you want to watch the solution converge in more real time,

```
import random
import itertools


def did_win(attempts):
    return any(random.random() < 0.01 for attempt in range(attempts))


wins = 0
for x in itertools.count(0):
    if did_win(6):
        wins += 1
    if x and x % 10_000 == 0:
        print(x, wins / x)
```

(hit ctrl-c to interrupt it – it'll otherwise happily run forever).

Answer (score 0):

The formula is much simpler, actually. The probability of *not* winning is `(99 / 100) ** 6`, that is approximately `0.941`. Its complement is the probability of winning `1 - 0.941... = 0.058...`.

Because you are increasing global counts in a weird way, it's very likely that you have off-by-one errors in more than one place. For instance

```
total += pick(k)
```

where `pick` also modifies `total`...

You should just return 0 or 1 and then count from outside.